# Volume resistivity

Tags: electrical-resistance

I know what resistivity of materials are like, and is given by the formula:

$$R = \frac{\rho L}{A}$$

However what is the volume resistivity of materials like copper and aluminium for instance? How do we calculate the volume resistivity of materials, because this was confusing when I read the site:

[Method of calculating eddy currents of a conductor, is this correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193501/)

Where there is the answer given by Floris states the equation:
$$F = \frac{v\cdot B^2\cdot A}{\rho/t}$$
Where $\rho$ is given to be the volume resisitivity.

My question:

1. how do we measure the volume resistivity of a material for example aluminium?
2. what happens if the thickness of the material changes?

Answer (score 0):

The volume resistivity is an intrinsic quantity of materials, just like masss density; meaning it doesn't depend on the amount of matter in materials. In other words, since $\rho$ is an intrinsic property, its value doesn't depends on the material size (to answer your second question).

(To answer your first question) Practically, you can measure it for a given material by sampling the material in question with different sizes and average the results. $\rho$ is calculated with rearranging the equation you mentioned:

$$ \rho = \frac{RA}{L}$$

You can certainly measure $R$ with multimeter/Ohmmeter, and A & L with your ruler.