# Should a Bismuth coin slide slowly down a magnetic ramp?

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, metals

One way to check for counterfeit silver/gold coins is to "slide" them down a ramp made of neodymium magnets. You can see an example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvmfTApZZsM), or just look up "silver slide". I have seen this work for various coins and it is claimed that this is due to "eddy current breaking" which occurs when a diamagnetic material is exposed to a changing magnetic field.

Pretty much the only coins I have tried that did not slide noticeably slower are modern nickles (75% Cu, 25% Ni) and American Gold Eagles (91.67% Au, 3% Ag, 5.33% Cu). The slowest coin was a modern dime (91.67% Cu, 8.33% Ni). I have quantitative data on all this but not sure if it adds much to figure out how to include a table here... but I saw a factor of ~6 difference.

I have read that bismuth is the most diamagnetic element, eg is [about 8x more diamagnetic than silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism#Materials).

So if I cast a round (ie, a coin) about the size of a quarter out of 99.99% bismuth should it slide slowly down a magnetic ramp?

Comment: This may be related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193501/method-of-calculating-eddy-currents-of-a-conductor-is-this-correct

Comment: that's none of your bismuth! This is a physics joke. you may laugh now.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the diamagnetic or paramagnetic properties of a material. I doubt even the diamagnetism of bismuth would matter. What matters is the electrical conductivity and probably the uniformity of the coin. Larger eddy currents will be induced in a more conductive coin, and the magnets will apply a greater force on it to oppose its motion down the slide.

Comment: @Puk would it help if I took the time to include a table of the speeds I collected for various coins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The eddy current breaking effect is very weak for bismuth because of its high electrical resistivity. The effect is strongest for pure silver and oxygen-free copper which have the lowest electrical resistivity. The effect is not caused by diamagnetism. This can be demonstrated using aluminum which is paramagnetic. Dropping a magnet into a thick aluminum pipe will slow the descent of the magnet just as in the more dramatic demonstration commonly done with copper ([video comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT16pLWqvXo)). The magnet falls more quickly in an aluminum pipe than in a copper one because aluminum has a higher electrical resistivity. If the pipe were made of bismuth, the effect would be minuscule.

A light diamagnetic substance such as pyrolytic graphite will levitate above the slide without contact friction. Bismuth is too dense to levitate itself over a magnet and its weak diamagnetism will not make a significant contribution to the sliding speed. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u36QpPvEh2c) for a demonstration.