# What is the retarding force due to eddy currents

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am currently struggling to find an expression to approximate the retarding force due to eddy currents when a magnet moves along at a speed $v$ beside a long, straight and flat conductive plate made of a metal that is not ferromagnetic.

It took a long time, but finally, I found this paper: https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/109373/me450w10project16_report.pdf?sequence=1

in which the force is approximated by the expression 
[image]

This expression, however, applies to a rotating disk, rather than a plate. I tried modifying it so that it would apply to a plate, like this:
[image]

Would this be appropriate? I am quite new to torque and I don't fully understand it yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method of calculating eddy currents of a conductor, is this correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193501)

Comment: Your formula $\frac{\dot\theta}{R}=v$ is incorrect. It should be $R\dot\theta=v$. $n$ is the number of magnets, which is your case is 1. This formula still contains $R$ which has no equivalent in your case.